# copy data between two dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different dataframes, both containing a common element (identifier). I want to copy data from df1 for each identifier in df2 (each identifier can repeat maximum 5 times in df1)

df1 ---data vertically

```
id_column         value1
identifier1       some data1     
identifier1       some data2
identifier1       some data3 
identifier2       some data2 
identifier2       some data1
identifier3       some data3
```

While df2 looks like this and this is how the information should be copied from df1:

df2 ---data horizontally

```
id_column        new1          new2           new3 

identifier1      some data1      some data2       some data3
identifier2      some data2      some data1 
identifier3      some data3
```

Is there a way to do this with python?

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the data from `df1` to `df2` you can use [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). Given that you want to keep all records from `df2` and only add data from `df1` for the identifiers in `df2` you can use the following syntax:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.merge(df2, df1, how="left", on="id_column")
```

Comment: thank you. I want to add data under specific columns but I don't know how to do that since the values under id_column are repeating in df1 - data is vertically while in df2 data is horizontally as in the example above

Comment: You can use [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to convert data from wide to long or [`pandas.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to reshape your data even more freely.